# How to manage "Meta title" and "Meta description" for pages in Drupal 8?

Tags: meta-tags, drupal-8

Just wanted to confirm that is there any stable version is released for "Meta title and Description" of a node in Drupal 8?

If yes then please recommend. I have a simple website of basic pages and few blogs for the same and for homepage I want to add "Meta title" and "Meta description".

So please suggest any appropriate option for **DRUPAL 8**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the `title` element? If yes, note that this is not a meta tag (`meta`).

Comment: @unor thanks for your response. I was asking about the "Meta titles" and "Meta description" that is needed and important for SEO.

Comment: But what is the "Meta title"?

Comment: I think you guys mean both the same thing. Although there is a <meta name="title"> tag, it is barely used by crawlers/search engines. Also some people refer to the title tag as the "meta title", for example: https://en.onpage.org/wiki/Meta_Title and onpage is really a big SEO agency here in Germany. IMHO in 99% of all cases meta title = title tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the "Metatag" module: https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag
It works great and I have no problems with it at all.

**EDIT:**

Just download and enable the module. Then add a new "Meta tags" field to your desired node type and now you should see the field when you edit the node.

Also important: under `/admin/config/search/metatag` you should be able to configure default meta values. So for example if your Title and Description follow always the same pattern like "{Node Title} | {Site Name}" for example, you can define it there. This way you don't have to set all the meta data yourself for every node.

Also settings for Homepage/Frontpage/Category Page etc. can be adjusted there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Frank, Thanks for your valuable response. I have installed this module. But can you confirm that with this module I can set unique "Meta title and Description" for all pages? My most pages are from "Basic page" and few are from a content type.

Comment: Also important: If you want to be able to overwrite the default pattern for a certain page, you need to add the Meta Tag content type to your node type as described in the [docu - Standard usage scenario](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/metatag/features-of-metatag-for-drupal-8)

Answer (score 0):

If you use metatag module and create pages with page manager, [here is a patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag/issues/2563657) you can apply and enable a new module metatag_page_manager. You can now configure meta tags for panel pages under /admin/config/search/metatag.